# Uno-Platform: How to embed JavaScript libraries in Uno-Platform Library?

Tags: uno-platform

**TL,DR:** How do I embed JavaScript into an Uno-Platform Cross Platform Library project?

### BACKGROUND

Below are some great resources on how to embed a JavaScript library into a WASM platform project of an Uno Platform ***Application*** (not a *Library*):

- [KazukiOta from Microsoft](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/how-to-use-javascript-libraries-on-uno-platform-webassembly/ba-p/1106524)
- [Uno Bootstrap docs](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap#support-for-additional-js-files)

### QUESTION

However, the above does not address, nor have I been able to find anything on, how to do this within an Uno Platform ***Library***.  How do I embed JavaScript into an Uno-Platform Cross Platform Library project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link shows how to do it - https://platform.uno/blog/how-to-embed-javascript-components-in-c-built-uno-webassembly-web-applications/

It has two examples on using a date/time picker control Flartpickr as well as syntax visualizer PrismJS.

Comment: Hi Sasha.  I may have missed it (very likely) but the examples I found all appear to be related to embedding JavaScript into an Uno WASM platform application - not a Uno Cross Platform Library.  Fortunately, I was able to figure out what I needed to do to the Uno Cross Platform Library's `.csproj` to get everything working and documented it as an answer to this question.

Comment: The steps are almost the same for both an app and a library. Let us know what you found that wasn't documented: we'll improve it.

Comment: @CarldeBilly - Yes, I had to add the below code to the Library's `.csproj` file to get it to work: `<ItemGroup Condition=" $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('netstandard2.')) ">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Filter" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Uno.UI.WebAssembly" Version="3.3.0" />
</ItemGroup>`

Comment: @CarldeBilly - Question:  Based on your comments about using `#if __WASM__` in the Library (to avoid collisions with Skai), what is your recommendation on how to implement the above addition to `.csproj` so a Skia collision won't happen?

Answer (score 2):

OK, I'm pretty embarrassed at how easy it was to get it to work.  After I created my Uno Platform Library project [using Uno Solution Templates in Visual Studio 2019](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/get-started-vs.html#installing-the-uno-platform-solution-templates-with-visual-studio), I then:

- Created a `WasmScripts` folder in the root of my library project
- Added my JavaScript file (`LibTest.js`) to the `WasmScripts` folder:

  ```js
  function libTest() {
    return 'IT WORKS!';
  }
  ```
- Created a class (`Test.cs`) that will use the above JavaScript function when targeting `NetStandard` - which is the target used by Uno WebAssembly apps:

  ```cs
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    #if !NETFX_CORE
    using Uno.Foundation;
    #endif

    namespace WasmTricksLib
    {
        public partial class Test
        {
            public static string PerformTestAsync()
            {
    #if __WASM__
                var result = WebAssemblyRuntime.InvokeJS("libTest()");
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("WasmTricksLib.Test.PerformTestAsync: RESULT=" + result);
                return result;
    #else   
                return "NOT THE RIGHT PLATFORM";
    #endif

            }
        }
    }
  ```

The above results in the following project structure for the library:

[image: Uno-Platform Library project structure]

So far, all the steps are what I expected to do, based upon the documentation for Uno-Platform apps projects.  However, it won't compile and VisualStudio IntelliSense will not like some of the code in `Test.cs`.

### THE SOLUTION

Add the following `<ItemGroup>` to the Uno-Platform Library's `.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('netstandard2.')) ">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Filter" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Uno.UI.WebAssembly" Version="3.3.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: You should add `#if __WASM__` instead of `#if NETSTANDARD` because this target is shared with Skia.

Comment: Carl - I may not be remembering this correctly, but I thought I had tried using `#if __WASM__` a few months back (in a Uno-Platform Library) and it didn't work.  Has that changed or am I remembering things wrong?

Comment: Carl - `#if __WASM__` does work in libraries!  Awesome!

Comment: @baskren - It would be great to have your solution also be contributed to Uno Platform documentation if you don't mind.

Comment: @sasha_krsmanovic: Done.